# How to show errors with simple_form with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have...

**/config/routes.rb:**

```
Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :areas do
    resources :heuristics    
  end
end
```

**/app/models/heuristic.rb:**

```
class Heuristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area_id, :blueprint_url
  belongs_to :area
  validates :blueprint_url, :presence => {:message => "Please type the blueprint's internet address"}
end
```

**/app/models/area.rb:**

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :heuristics
end
```

**/app/controllers/heuristics_controller.rb:**

```
class HeuristicsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @heuristic = Heuristic.find(params[:id])
  end
 def update
  @heuristic = Heuristic.find(params[:id])
  @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @heuristic.update_attributes(params[:heuristic])
      format.html { redirect_to areas_path, notice: 'Heuristic was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to edit_area_heuristic_path(@area, @heuristic) }
      format.json { render json: @heuristic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
 end
end
```

**/app/views/heuristics/new.html.haml:**

```
%h1 New heuristic
= render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', area_heuristics_path(@area)
```

**/app/views/heuristics/_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for [@area, @heuristic] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :blueprint_url
  = f.button :submit
```

As expected, the app won't let me save an update with an empty :blueprint_url.

However, the error notice is not appearing, and I think it's because simple_form doesn't know whether to display errors for @area or @heuristic or something else.

How do I get it to display my errors?

The rdoc says you can pass options to error_notifications, but it doesn't say what option to pass in a situation like this.

[http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:error_notification](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder%3aerror_notification)

Thanks,

Steven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you display the errors is by rendering a template when the update fails rather than redirecting. When you redirect you are losing all of that error state.

```
def update
  @heuristic = Heuristic.find(params[:id])
  @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @heuristic.update_attributes(params[:heuristic])
      format.html { redirect_to areas_path, notice: 'Heuristic was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render "edit" } # This is the thing that will get your error state
      format.json { render json: @heuristic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```